# How to separate the entries of an output file of a select starlet xml command?

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I use the starlet xml to find some artifactIds from a pom.xml and i redirect the output to a temporary file, so i can later to create an array with these entries. The problem is that the entries in the temporary file are like one word and they are not separated and when i create the array then the length is 1 instead of 3 for example. The code i wrote is:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -m "x:project/x:dependencies/x:dependency[x:groupId = '$GROUP_ID']/x:artifactId" -v . $POM_XML > temporary


ARRAY=(`cat temporary`)
```

and the results are for example:

```
my-name-is-jonmy-name-is-georgemy-name-is-nick
```

but i would like to be like:

```
my-name-is-jon my-name-is-george my-name-is-nick
```

How can i set a field separator for the temporary? Because as long as the temporary file has them as one entry, my array will also have length 1.. I need to do it with a bash script.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the back quotes, it was a copy-paste mistake of mine

Comment: You pasted properly, you forgot to mark your code with the `{}` tool to indent it. In inline text, SO uses backticks to mark embedded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `-o " "` after `-v .` (Or `-o whatever-separator-string-you-want`)